# Angular animations: add parameters to template trigger

Tags: css, angular, animation, sass

So I'm making a profile page and when the page loads I want 4 different text boxes to move in different directions to their start spot (bottom position becomes left, left becomes top,...)

I could make a different trigger for each of the text boxes, but that doesn't seem like best practice. I tried adding parameters to the template trigger (see below), this way I can just add the left and top position (all text boxes are absolute positioned) without making a new trigger for every element.

However it gives me an error so I must be using wrong syntax. There's not much documentation on this. Does someone know the correct syntax for this? Because I looked around and it's hard to find.

**The error, the comma is wrong.**

```
Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token , at column 24 in [{params: {left_pos: 50%, top_pos: 95%}}] in ng:///AppModule/FindLocalsComponent.html@43:19 ("ileSection__data">{{ focussedUser?.birthDate | age}}</h3>
              </div>
              <div [ERROR ->][@moveText]="{params: {left_pos: 50%, top_pos: 95%}}" class="header-box header-box--left">
```

**The template: I tried the trigger (@moveText) on the left box**

```
<div class="profileSection" [ngClass]="{
      'visible': markerClicked,
      'not-visible': !markerClicked}
    ">
            <!--there should be a profile picture displayed here-->
            <!-- Other details that we want to display are conencted to the game, such details are currently unknown as we don't know more about the game-->
            <div class="profileSection__header" *ngIf="markerClicked">
              <img class="profileSection__img" *ngIf="!focussedUser?.profilePicture.uploaded" src="assets/images/blank-profile-picture.png" alt="no profile picture">
              <img class="profileSection__img" *ngIf="focussedUser?.profilePicture.uploaded" [src]="'assets/images/profile-pictures/' + focussedUser?.profilePicture.name" alt="the profile picture">
              <div class="header-box header-box--top">
                <h3 class="profileSection__data">{{ focussedUser?.username }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="header-box header-box--right">
                <h3 class="profileSection__data">Slytherin</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="header-box header-box--bottom">
                <h3 class="profileSection__data">{{ focussedUser?.birthDate | age}}</h3>
              </div>
              <div [@moveText]="{params: {left_pos: 50%, top_pos: 95%}}" class="header-box header-box--left">
                <h3 class="profileSection__data">Speciality: Potions</h3>
              </div>
              <button class="btn profileSection__btn profileSection__btn--first">Send PM</button>
              <button class="btn profileSection__btn profileSection__btn--sec">Visit Profile</button>
            </div>
```

**the component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'find-locals',
    styleUrls: ['find-locals.component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'find-locals.component.html',
    animations: [
      trigger('moveText', [
        state('start', style({
          left: '{{ left_pos }}',
          top: '{{ top_pos }}'
        }), {params: {left_pos: 0, top_pos: 0}}),
        transition(':enter', [animate(2000)])
      ])
]
})
```

**scss: these are how the text blocks are positioned. I took an image below of how it's supposed to look after the animations. e.g the left text box starts at the position and moves to it's destined place when the animation starts**

```
.header-box {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 20%;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: center;

      &--top {
        top: 5%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }

      &--right {
        top: 50%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }

      &--bottom {
        top: 95%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }

      &--left {
        top: 50%;
        left: 5%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
    }
```

**The right side of the screen is where I want the animation to happen. there is text on bottom, right, left and top side.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to treat the percentage values as strings.

Change the HTML to:

```
[@moveText]="{params: {left_pos: '50%', top_pos: '95%'}}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Now however my component doesn't load anymore and it doesn't give an error in the console :s